# How to receive an event when selected option is the already selected option of a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome

## Motivation:

I want to dynamically load a `select` with values from an AJAX call, and allow the user to *select* the first item in the list once it is loaded and *after* it gets focus, right now, the first item is the *selected* item and when you click the dropdown and click the first item nothing happens. I can't add any placeholder items that are not valid selections.

## Question:

How do you fire the `.change` event in jQuery when the currently selected option is reselected / not changed?

Given the following :

```
<select id="myoptions">
  <option id="one" >Option 1</option>
  <option id="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Assuming that option `one` is selected, and I click on the dropdown and *select* `one` again, what event fires?

```
$('#myoptions').change(function() {
    alert('You selected something!');
}
```

The above code works if I select something different, but if I select the currently selected option nothing happens.

In other words :

**If I click on the dropdown and *"select"* the currently selected option, how do I get an event to fire?**

## Not Answers:

All these suggestions about `trigger` are not solutions, I need something that fires when I **click** on `Option 1` **with the mouse** when `Option 1` is already the selected option.

I tried using `.click` and nothing happens then either.

None of the answers is a working solution for the use case of the **very first time** the dropdown is selected, and someone *selects* the default selected option. Nothing happens.

`focusout` is not a solution, it doesn't happen until someone clicks somewhere else, which is too late in the game.

Comment: Responding to a non-change of state isn't generally a good idea. That's why `select` elements behave the way they do.

Comment: I would suggest just add a Empty item or an item with something like [Select]

Comment: "I can't add any placeholder items that are not valid selections". Why not? A placeholder as first option is the standard approach to this issue. If you can populate/insert the select element then you have full control.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot because I can't, part of the requirements.

Comment: If you are willing to have the `<select>` list appear onscreen as more than one row, you can use `size` combined with `value` to "unset" the currently selected option.  Then the same option selection will trigger repeatedly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136844/5025060.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working Solution:

First you have to explicitly set the first item to a `selected` state.

```
<select id="myoptions">
  <option id="one" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option id="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Then in your JavaScript you must explicitly remove the `selected` attribute.

```
$('#myoptions option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

$("#myoptions").on("change", function(){
    console.debug($('#myoptions').find('option:selected').val());
});
```

This will then show a blank/empty drop down box on initialization. Which will allow you to select the first item in the list the first time you click on the dropdown because no `option` has the `selected` attribute anymore.

This has the benefit of having the look of a blank placeholder selection without actually having to have one and write all the convoluted logic to handle when it gets selected.

[CodePen working example of the solution.](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-dynamically-load-a-dropdown-with-data-from-an-ajax-call-and-allow-selection-of-the-first-element-in-the-list/) *Be sure and have your JavaScript debug console open before you click on the link or you won't see the desired effect.*

This still doesn't solve the *reselection* issue that so many other people have asked about which is a similar problem, which I would like to use as a *refresh* mechanism, but I will tackle that in another question.

Comment: Hi Jarrod I think I solved the reselection issue just a while ago. I've posted it in this SO question [How to reselect already selected option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234805/how-to-reselect-already-selected-option/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the click event or the focusout.
Click event will not work if the user is using only keyboard like tab + enter but focusout will work.

**Edit:**

Added a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fPRe7/
Click works even you click a selected item.

```
$("#myoptions").on("click", function(){
    console.debug("click");
});

$("#myoptions").on("change", function(){
    console.debug("changed");
});
$("#myoptions").on("focusout", function(){
    console.debug("focusout");
});
```

Chrome will get only 1 click (the choose one), but FF will get 2 clicks, one click when you open the select and another when choose one.

Comment: this doesn't work the way I am requesting, on first run, select `Option 1` as the very first thing you do, when you `click` it none of your events fires. `focusout` is not what I need, it is too late in the game for me by that point.

Comment: If you need a fire event in your first click (the click that open the select) you can use the focusin. http://jsfiddle.net/fPRe7/1/

Comment: that doesn't work if the dropdown already has focus; and I don't want to automatically run when it receives focus, I want it to fire an event after it receives focus and AFTER you click on the already selected item.

Comment: The click event works on ff and chrome, I didnt test in others browsers. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am running latest Chrome > OSX, `.click` never fires in my tests nor your jsFiddle.

Comment: OSX 10.8.3 - Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65

Comment: That is odd, I'm using chromium and the click works on first click and the reselect click.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I have found is to use the option click event

```
$(document).on('click', 'select#myselect option', function(){
      doStuff(this.value);
});
```

it will be called no matter what is previously selected. And it doesn't mess up what is shown as the selected option in your select control (which will happen if you deselect it with removeAttr('selected'))

Comment: This does not work on chrome and most other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.trigger()` function to fire custom events on elements.

```
$("#yourelementid").trigger('change'):
```

This way you can trigger the `change` event on element with id `yourelementid`

Now since you want this to happen when you click on the dropdown and select the previous element. Adding a click event should do it.

```
$("#yourelementid").on('click', function() {
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myoptions').change(function(e){
       alert('You selected something!');
    });

    // And now fire change event when the DOM is ready
    $('#myoptions').trigger('change');
});
```