# How to reselect already selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

The title seems confusing but what I want to do is...

I know how to handle only if the user select new option with this - `$('select').change(function(){})`.`

But not if the user wants to select the already selected option.

I've also tried with `radio` but same thing.

Okay for example I have a select with an option (red,blue,green).

```
<select>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="green">GREEN</option>
</select>
```

and I have this script:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

When I select option 'blue' it alerts a value 'blue', then I select 'green' it alerts 'green' as well. but when I select 'green' again nothing happens.

Comment: not getting what you are trying to explain.... please be more specific

Comment: Have you tried with radio `click()`?

Comment: If you are using a select tag I would make the selected option like "Please Select a Value" then you can check when you submit it that if it has the generic value to prompt the user that the select field needs to be changed.

Comment: Try using `.blur()` event.

Comment: With blur it seems that I need to click elsewhere to remove the focus on select so that function is fired.

Comment: hmmm.. radio with click handler seems to be good alternative. thanks Mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question comes to my attention as this is pretty basic stuff but no one actually dig into it further. OP has been using `change()`, but when you reselect the current selected option nothing is fired!

I tried `click()`, but it's firing before you can even choose an option.

With `blur()`, after you're done selecting nothing is fired because the the select element is still being focused, so you need to focus out like clicking outside for it to execute.

So I just suggested OP to switch to a `radio` type input then handle execution with `click()` event. That way you can still reselect already marked radio button.

But then I noticed that you just need to get the second click on `<select>` element because the first click opens the drop down list of options the second click returns the value of your selected option. So I came up with this:

```
$('select').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
        alert($this.val());
        $this.removeClass('open');
    }else {
        $this.addClass('open');
    }  
});
```

But now the problem is when you first click on `<select>` the drop down is being showned and we've also added the class `'open'`. Then clicking elsewhere (without selecting an option) the drop down is hidden so when you click back on `<select>` the event is fired before you can even select an option.

So I added this code to fix that:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   var $select = $('select');

    if (!$select.is(e.target)){
        $select.removeClass('open'); //reset the steps by removing open
    }
});
```

You can test it out in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/fef7j/). Cheers!

---

I think when `<select>` loses its focus is also a concern. So I added `blur()` event. See this update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/fef7j/1/)

Comment: I've tested this on Chrome and Firefox and it's working fine. Can someone also please confirm on other browsers. Thanks

Comment: Oh this is great and very good explanation! Many thanks again. I've tested it on IE 11 & 10 and it's working well.

Comment: What about event on the `<option>` elements? Can we put a click listener on those?

Answer (score 1):

i solved using `onclick='this.value=-1'` that reset the selection to nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using:

```js
$('#id_selec').on('click', 'option', function (e) {
    value = $(this).val();
    // ....
```

The handler works if you select any (including the already selected) option.

Answer (score -1):

In instances where nothing should happen when the user selects the already-selected option I suppose it is a "feature" of the DOM rather than a bug to have no Event occur.  However, if your code is doing more with `<select>` than making a simple selection it is also a nuisance, so I'm grateful others have tackled it here.

The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20240318/5025060) is clever in the use of the click event to capture selection of an already selected `<select>` option, but ***if you are willing to specify the length of your list*** as (in this case) `<select size=3>`, you can simply set the selected value to "" from your "change" Event, and the same selection will trigger every time.

In this case [the OP's example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20234805/5025060) would change to:

**HTML:**

```
<select size=3>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="green">GREEN</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
    $('select').val("");
});
```

The only side-effect is that ***the selection element may now display to the user as three rows rather than one***.

(Credit goes to [Kirby L. Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214125/5025060) for the idea of setting the select's `value` to "").