# Trigger function when already selected option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function when already selected OPTION is select from drop-down.

```js
$("#dropdown1").on("change",function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown1">
  <option value="one"> One </option>
  <option value="two"> Two </option>
  <option value="three"> Three </option>  
</select>
```

In above code, when i select option ONE than ALERT works.
So, now option ONE is selected. But i want that when i select option ONE again, than function should call again.

Comment: You can think of `click` instead of `change`....as it not logically correct when ONE is already selected, you will select that again.

Comment: It would be easier if you can store the earlier selected value to a variable and check if the newly selected value matches the existing value and if yes, then proceed with your alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reselect already selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234805/how-to-reselect-already-selected-option)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select , where one can use `onclick` method to replicate the required behavior.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Thanks man. found solution from there.    [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/fef7j/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is change, if you select the same value again then there is no change, so no alert is fired.Introduce a dummy option which is hidden. Make all the calculations/manipulation you want to do with the selected value and then change the value to the dummy option element

```js
$("#dropdown1").on("change",function(){
  alert($(this).val());
  $(this).val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown1">
 <option value="" disabled  style="display:none;">Select</option>
  <option value="one" selected> One </option>
  <option value="two"> Two </option>
  <option value="three"> Three </option>  
</select>
```

Comment: The select dialog box becomes empty after selecting a value.

Comment: Thanks @AshayMandwarya. It works. I got one more solution..[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/fef7j/1/)...

Comment: One of the options just disappear after the first click

Comment: That option is hidden on purpose

Comment: It does not disappear, after the change event and alert the value is again given to the default option so that next time if you click the same option change event fires