# How to work with event.detail in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have function preventing selecting element, under other clicking element. Fumction works fine in chrome, but in IE11, e.detail doesn`t work.
What use instead? How to reorganize function code?

```
function xorClick(e) {

    if (pendingClick) {
        clearTimeout(pendingClick);
        pendingClick = 0;
    }

    switch (e.detail) {
        case 1:
            pendingClick = setTimeout(function() {
                var parent = e.target.closest('.ui-treenode-content');
                parent.click();                
            }, 180);
            break;
        case 2:
            var parent = e.target.closest('.ui-treenode-content');
            parent.firstChild.click();
            break;
        default:
            break; 
    }
    stopClick(e);
```

I tried to use

```
    var nDelta = e.detail === 0 ? e.wheelDelta : e.delta;
```

But it is not working too.

```
function stopClick(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```
                                    <span onclick="xorClick(event)">
                                        <div onclick="stopClick(event)">
                                            .....
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
```

Comment: I made a test in IE and looks like it is not working in IE. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16710370/ Also it is tagged as 'won't fix'. So I suggest you to use any work around for IE. You can refer link below may help to work around the issue. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dn905219(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [IE11 docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ms536913(v=vs.71)):

> Note  Starting with Internet Explorer 11, this event fires a
>   MSPointerEvent object instead of MouseEvent. You can use the
>   `MouseEvent.pointerType` property to determine the type of contact that
>   the click originated from (touch, mouse, or pen).

From what I can see in difference between `e.detail` in IE11 and Firefox/Edge is that IE11 returns 0, but the others return 1. Maybe you just have to add that case in your `switch` statement?

Comment: Thank you, I tried but there was an error that IE dont support "closest" method

Comment: e.detail returns 0 always, but I need some operations for 1 click and the other operations for 2 click.